# Boolean returns nil and unable to access value from response on view controller

Tags: swift, boolean, viewcontroller

I have a usermodel that checks the backend if the email exists - then I drill back into a viewcontroller and set a boolean value that should trigger a function run. However the value is unchanged and I am trying to change this value from the usermodel but it is not accessible. I understand why it does not work.. but do not know how to resolve the issue.

```
static func sendEmailWithResetLink(email: String) {
        let params : Parameters = [
            PARAM_EMAIL : email
        ]
        request(URL_RESET_PASSWORD as String, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
            hideProgress()
            print("this is response \(response)")
            switch(response.result)
                      {
                      case .success(_):
                       print("it did not fail")
                       let passwordResetVC = PasswordResetViewController()
                       passwordResetVC.hasFailed = false
                          break

                      case .failure(_):
                        print("it failed")
                        let passwordResetVC = PasswordResetViewController()
//here boolean is set that I am trying to access in viewcontroller 
                        passwordResetVC.hasFailed = true   
                          break
                      }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `PasswordResetViewController()` is invoking the initializer of `PasswordResetViewController` to produce a new object, seperate from the one you're probably looking at. Instead, you need to set `hasFailed` on the existing VC object that you already have. Most probably, you should be using a `segue` to establish a relationship between this VC and your existing `PasswordResetViewController`, and use it to save a reference to the existing `PasswordResetViewController` as an instant member of your current VC. Then you call `myExistingPasswordResetVC.hasFailed = ...`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am not sure I understand... the current page this is being called on is not a view controller but a custom class - userModel on which the existing user is defined. But that is where the backend is accessed to grab the response

Comment: That's fine. Still applies. Your current scope (`UserClass`, some kind of class, struct, whatever) needs access to the view controller object it wants to update. What you're doing is creating a new VC object, and setting properties on it which will never have any significance, since this object is distinct from the one that's driving all of the UI. In this case, segues aren't applicable for establishing this relationship. Instead, you should probably look into using the "delegate pattern". Though more fundamentally, it's not the job of a user model to be driving user interface changes ...

Comment: I'll cook up an answer, my comment is too long

Comment: Maybe you can simply create a variable globally on your userModel like `var passwordResetVC: PasswordResetViewController `, and when you initiate your userModel to call `sendEmailWithResetLink(email:)` (probably you do that on `PasswordResetViewController `) you can atribute your vc to this variable like: `userModel.passwordResetVC = self` then when you call `sendEmailWithResetLink ` change the `hasFailed` of your passwordResetVC without creating a new one inside the method

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thank you!!!!

Comment: @RomuloBM no, that's madness. Models should not know about view controllers.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, sure, you are right, but in my mind all that logic shouldn't be in model. I'm think all these things should be on a viewModel. But i don't know what architecture she's using, i just want to explain in a simple way what it`s wrong with the code with a functional example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would suggest. You probably have some of these in place already:

1. Create an `PasswordResetViewController` object has an `@IBAction func resetButtonClicked` triggered by a button or whatever, which kicks off the password reset process.
2. Create a `UserManager` class. This class is responsible for all profile management activies in your app. Among other things, it has the ability to reset user passwords. This `UserManager` would probably be a singleton, that' sprobably good enough for now.
3. Create a new `UserManagerDelegate` protocol. Add to it all capabilities that are required by the `UserManager` to inform them of whatever happened. For example: `var passwordResetHasFailed: Bool { get set }`.
4. Extend your `PasswordResetViewController` conform to this protocol.
5. Your VC gets a reference to the singleton `UserManager` object, stores it in an instance variable, and uses that to access the shared object from then on.
6. Make your `PasswordResetViewController` register itself as the delegate to the user manager, with `userManager.delegate = self`
7. The `@IBAction func resetButtonClicked` will just call `userManager.resetPassword()`
8. Your `UserManager` does whatever it needs to do to reset the user's password.
9. When it's done, it'll call `self.delegate?.passwordResetHasFailed = true/false`.
10. Since your `PasswordResetViewController` registered itself as the delegate of the `UserManager`, when the operation is done, its `passwordResetHasFailed` property will be changed, giving it a chance to respond (by updating some UI or whatever).

There are some limitations to this approach, but it's a decent way to get started. Some thing to note:

1. This lets you unit test your `PasswordResetViewController`. You can create a `MockUserManager`, and set `tesPasswordResetViewController.userManager = MockUserManager()`, allowing you to separate out the user manager, and test `PasswordResetViewController` in isolation.
2. You'll run into issues if you need multiple objects to subscribe to receive delegate call backs (since there can only be 1 delegate object). At that point, you can switch to using something like Promises, RxSwift or Combine. But that's a problem for a later time, and the migration would be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @Alexander - Reinstate Monica and what I assume what the code to look like to approach your problem.

Using MVC:

In Models folder (data/ logic part)

```
public class User {
private var name: String!
private var userEmail: String!
public var hasFailed: Bool?

init() {
    name = ""
    userEmail = ""
    hasFailed = nil
}

public func setName(name: String) { self.name = name }

public func getName() -> String { return name }

public func setEmail(email: String) { userEmail = email }

public func getEmail() ->String { return userEmail }

public static func sendEmailWithRestLing(email: String) {
    // your other code

    switch response.result {
    case .success(_):
        //your code
        hasFailed = false
        break
    case .failuare(_):
        // your code
        hasFailed = true
        break
    }
}
}
```

User Manager class applying singleton design

```
final class UserManager {
private var user = User()
static let instance = UserManager()

private init(){}

public func userName(name: String) {
    if (name.count > 3) {
        user.setName(name: name)
    }
    else { print("user name is too short") }
}

public func userEmail(email: String) {
    if (email.count > 3) {
        user.setEmail(email: email)
    }
    else { print("user email is too short") }
}

public func getUserName() -> String {
    let name = user.getName()

    if (name.isEmpty) { return "user name is Empty" }

    return name
}

public func getUserEmail() -> String {
    let email = user.getEmail()

    if (email.isEmpty) { return "user email is Empty" }

    return email
}

public func doKatieTask(link: String) -> Int {
    guard let myValue = user.hasFailed else {
        return -1
    }

    if (myValue) { return 1}

    return 0
}
}
```

So, Now in the Controllers folder and since we a one-to-one relation we will use delegate design pattern. If had had one-to-many with the view controller. Use observers.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var  emailTextField: UITextField!

var _hasFail: Bool!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func doTask() {
    UserManager.instance.userName(name: nameTextField.text!)
    UserManager.instance.userEmail(email: emailTextField.text!)

    switch UserManager.instance.doKatieTask(link: emailTextField.text!) {
    case 0:
        _hasFail = false
        break
    case 1:
        _hasFail = true
        break
    default:
        print("hasFailed is nil")
        break
    }

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "passwordVC") as? PasswordResetViewController {
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        vc.delegate = self
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

}

extension ViewController: KatieDelegate {
var hasFailed: Bool {
    get {
        return _hasFail
    }
    set {
        _hasFail = newValue
    }
}
}
```

In PasswordReset UIViewController

```
protocol KatieDelegate {
    var hasFailed: Bool { get set }
}


class PasswordResetViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

var delegate: KatieDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nameLabel.text = UserManger.instance.getUserName()
    emailLabel.text = UserManger.instance.getUserEmail()

    if let delegate = delegate {
        print("The value for has failed is: .....\(delegate.hasFailed)!")
    }
    else { print("error with delegate") }


}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I had in mind. Not a fan of fruitless abbreviations like `lbl` over `label` (key strokes are free; use them). That `deinit` is unnecessary tho.

Comment: Bad habits I need to break. A few things I think I should point out.
1. Using an optional type for the delegate in Swift also means it is automatically set to nil. So, Access property using optional chaining.
2. using singleton is when you're creating only one instance in your app. That's why I set init() to private so one does not end up making additional initializers.
3. Adhere to @Alexander - Reinstate Monica post caution when using this approach.